# JavaScript textbox blank value

Tags: javascript

I have a friend who made a website for me and I want to change something.

I have this code:

```
$(".res.mobile input#cloth").keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $(".number.cloth.mobile").text( value );
});
  .keyup();
```

So basically whatever value you put in, it will use it on the website. But if the value is blank, it won't show anything (obviously). So what I need is to show a number "10" if the field is blank. If the field does contain value, then just show the value provided.

Comment: The selector at least makes little sense, ID's are unique, so just `$('#cloth')` should do it. Then you're looking for an element *with* **all** three classes ?

Comment: Please edit your question to use code blocks. Snippets are for runnable javascript code.

Comment: And editing your question, you clearly have a syntax error

Comment: Update `$(".number.cloth.mobile").text( value );` to `$(".number.cloth.mobile").text( value === '' ? '10' : value );`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: so learn how to code and use an if....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else